# Change session name in screen

Tags: debian, terminal, gnu-screen

I am running multiple programs with different values for some variables in "screen". I want to change the name of the screen-sessions so I can identify them with "screen -ls" to revert to them.

Which option do I have to use for it? And is there a way to change the session name while the screen is running already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name a session when starting it with the `-S name` option. From  within a running screen, you can change it by typing

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>:</kbd> followed by `sessionname name`<sup>(1)</sup>.

You can view running screen sessions with `screen -ls`, and connect to one by name with

```
screen -xS name
```

<sub>(1):`name` is and an arbitrary string which will become the new session name. If the session name contains whitespace, quote it with single or double quotes.</sub>

Within a single screen session, you can also name each window. Do this by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> then the name you want. You can view an interactive list of named windows by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, and select the one you want to switch to from that list.

Naming both screens and terminals within screens is really helpful for remembering what they are and why you started them in the first place.

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27294/454022)

Comment: I am using a german keyboard, so : is not an option. Do you know which key that would be?

Comment: @73CHN0M4NC3R I am also using a german keyboard and it works fine for me. Note that you need to enter `:` after you've pressed `Strg` + `A`, not all at the same time.